# Windows 8.1 how to boot to BIOS on HP when it skips to setup after I hit f10

Tags: windows-8, boot, bios

So here's the deal, I know this has been asked a million times but this time its different. I have fixed countless computers and never run into this yet.

I have a HP Envy 4-1195ca. I want to boot tot the bios so I can boot from a USB key. When you hit esc on boot it boots to a selection menu allowing you to do things like See system info, or change bootup options or change bios settings. Bootup is "F9" bios is "F10" If i hit either of those two, it doesn't go to those things, it goes to the HP logo saying please wait and then into the standard windows 8 default advanced screen where you can reset windows etc. I thought maybe I have to hit those keys on boot. So I tried, it quickly flashes saying "F10 Bios Setup Options" and then process to the HP logo and advanced windows setup screen. Have any of you had this issue before? If you have how in the world did you fix it?

The computer is running windows 8.1

Comment: Seriosuly,  am about to remove the hard drive just to see if I can get it to boot so I can change the boot order.

Comment: Update: Removing the HDD allows me to boot into BIOS. After I did this I changed the boot settings to boot from USB first as well as turned off secure boot and changed boot mode to legacy mode. After putting the HDD back into the system It overwrote all my old changes automatically and then came back with  the same issue I just had.

Comment: Apparently with that model, you first need to hit the *Esc* key to get you into the boot menu, then press *F10* to get into the BIOS.

Comment: Yeah it does the same thing as I stated above, still just boots to HP startup.

Answer (score 0):

Ok well i figured it out, after way too long and now I feel stupid. Heres how to do it:

When the system boots, you hit the esc key or you hit F10 it doesnt matter. If you hit the ESC key then you must hit f10 after the options window pops up. Wait for HP startup to load and go to Troubleshooting then advanced and then Boot into UEFI bios. It'll ask if you wanna restart and you say yes. Then hit ESC again on boot, and hit F10 again for BIOS, this time it will actually load the BIOS. Then you can make the changes you need. If you want to boot into a USB the steps are similar except you hit F9 after the second boot.